# Проблема npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

Переустановил себе node js. Сейчас клонировал проект. npm install выводит вот такие ошибки:
Ничего не работает в итоге. Что можно с этим сделать?

```
PS C:\Users\Екатерина\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege> npm install
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.      
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Екатерина\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Екатерина\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Екатерина\\Downloads\\newProject\\rv-privilege\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.12.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python311\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.11.0"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.0 found at "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 18.12.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '18.12.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "18.12.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 18.12.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 18.12.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\Users\Екатерина\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\Users\Екатерина\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32929.386) found at:
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.19041.0
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.32929.386) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\Users\Екатерина\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:4192) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\Екатерина\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\Екатерина\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python311\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Екатерина\\Downloads\\newProject\\rv-privilege\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Екатерина\\Downloads\\newProject\\rv-privilege\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Екатерина\\Downloads\\newProject\\rv-privilege\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Екатерина\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.12.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Екатерина\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.12.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Екатерина\\Downloads\\newProject\\rv-privilege\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Екатерина\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.12.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Екатерина\\Downloads\\newProject\\rv-privilege\\node_modules\\node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Екатерина\\Downloads\\newProject\\rv-privilege\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\���������\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 51, in <module>
npm ERR!     sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
npm ERR!              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\���������\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 670, in script_main
npm ERR!     return main(sys.argv[1:])
npm ERR!            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\���������\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 662, in main
npm ERR!     return gyp_main(args)
npm ERR!            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\���������\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 629, in gyp_main
npm ERR!     [generator, flat_list, targets, data] = Load(
npm ERR!                                             ^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\���������\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 150, in Load
npm ERR!              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\���������\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 3021, in Load
npm ERR!     LoadTargetBuildFile(
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\���������\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 411, in LoadTargetBuildFile
npm ERR!     build_file_data = LoadOneBuildFile(
npm ERR!                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\���������\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 239, in LoadOneBuildFile
npm ERR!     build_file_contents = open(build_file_path, "rU").read()
npm ERR!                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! ValueError: invalid mode: 'rU' while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\Екатерина\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:351:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Екатерина\\Downloads\\newProject\\rv-privilege\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" 
"--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Екатерина\Downloads\newProject\rv-privilege\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Екатерина\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-28T08_27_59_656Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Python 3.11 отсутствует в списке версий, которые требует node-gyp. Попробуйте использовать 3.10?

Comment: А как можно спуститься до этой версии?

Comment: Я установил python 3.10 и теперь у меня стоят и 3.11 и 3.10. Как я понимаю, теперь мне надо установить ключ npm config set python /path/to/executable/python Но я не оч понимаю, какой путь прописать до python

Comment: Ну вот куда у Вас установился 3.10? Вот этот путь и прописать